# Mysql - grouping 1 to many join

Tags: mysql

Using the following tables:

```
products
product_id  |  name
1           |  Jeans
2           |  t-shirt

options
option_id   | product_id | option_name |  option_value
1           | 1          | size        |  32
2           | 1          | colour      |  blue
3           | 1          | price       |  100
4           | 2          | colour      |  red
```

I would like to run a query for a product and get back a single row containing the product data combined with the options for that product.  The issue is the 1 to many relationship between the products and the options.

Is this possible in anyway maybe grouping them or having multiple columns in the result for each option?

Comment: Use `GROUP_CONCAT` to concatenate all the options for a product ID.

Comment: What are your expected results?  You can group them with `group_concat`...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - Rows to Columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241178/mysql-rows-to-columns)

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT`.

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.name, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(o.option_name, ' ', o.option_value)) AS options
FROM products AS p
LEFT JOIN options AS o ON p.product_id = o.product_id
GROUP BY p.product_id
```

I use `LEFT JOIN` so that products with no options will still be listed (with an empty `options` column). Use `INNER JOIN` if you don't want to see those products in the results.